# Accessing WAR-packaged classpath resources from within Spring container on Weblogic 9.x

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, weblogic, war

Inside web application I use some Spring scheduled-tasks (so managed standalone by Spring container). These tasks execute some business logic and require access to StringTemplate resources, which after deployment are located in WEB-INF/classes. I provide their directory as String (i.e. `"some/templates"`) which works fine when working in exploded mode, but after switching to WAR-packaging, these resources cannot be found by ST. [Project's page](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Using+StringTemplate+with+Java) suggest using URL/URI (the "quagmire"), but that's a bit unclear to me. Other resources work properly, the only problem is the `STGroupDir` constructor.

How should I construct URL/URI/Paths arguments so that these resources could be accessed by WAR-packaged Spring-managed scheduled-tasks?

Comment: Did you try `YourClass.class.getResource("some/templates").getPath()`?

Comment: Yes, though the problem was located strictly in STGroupDir constructor. As mentioned in one of the links I attached to my answer below, getResurceAsStream is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared to be an issue with Weblogic 9.x creating an internal `_wl_cls_gen.jar` within the packaged WAR, containing all the classpath (i.e. WEB-INF/classes) resources. This results in problems with many frameworks that rely on `getResource(path)` methods (such as the `ClassLoader` one). Because of that `StringTemplate` could not access the group files. I fixed the problem by moving the templates out of the classpath and to `WEB-INF` location, then injecting the path as URL for `StringTemplate` to use.

I found some further information regarding this issue [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=408) and [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4217650#4217650).